# call a dictionary from another class to main class and set its value to combobox

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I made a text file which contain a city name and Many interesting places name of that city. I want that when a city name appear on first combobox the 2nd combobox will show all the places name automatically.

to do that, at the the first step I filled the 1st combobox with city name which I get from a large .xls file. then I made the text file with city and place name of that city. it looks like this-

```
Flensburg;Nordertor;Naval Academy Mürwik;Flensburg Firth
Kiel;Laboe Naval Memorial;Zoological Museum of Kiel University
Lübeck;Holstentor;St. Mary's Church, Lübeck;Passat (ship)
```

I create dictionary in a separate method and now I want to to call this method in the main form. Well I am trying it in this way. But it is not actually working.

For data input I wrote the code as follows-

```
public class POI
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public void poiPlace()
    {                            
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("POIList.txt"))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>());
            poi[parts[0]] = new List<string>(parts.Skip(1));
         }
    }
```

Now I want to call this in the main form

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();                       
         POI poi1 =new POI();
         poi1.List();                     
     }
     public void Combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if (Combo_list1.SelectedItem != null)
          {
              string txt = Combo_list1.SelectedItem.ToString();
              if (poi.ContainsKey(txt))
              {
                  List<string> points = poi[txt];
                  Combo_list2.Items.Clear();
                  Combo_list2.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());
              }
          }
      }
```

It does not work at all.

Comment: What does "not working" mean in particular? What is the content of `poi` when debugging? Btw.: Can ommit the line `poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>())` as you override its value on the next one.

Comment: I set key to 1st combobox, now I want to set value for 2nd combobox. The list I mention in the description.

Comment: The question is not about "what you expect to get" but rather what you get INSTEAD - in particular: what is the content of `poi` when you get to the eventhalnder?

Comment: poiPlace() is not invoked from anywhere. Is this correct or did i miss something?

Comment: @Martin I have modified my code in the answer section. What I want to do is that I already set City names in the first combobox. Then  I make a text file Which contain city name that included in the first combobox and places name of that city. Now I make a dictionary to set city name as key and place name as value. I want to change the 2nd combobox according to the key of the first combobox. I have modified my code in the answer section. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not call `poiPlace` anywhere which will set the `poi`-dictionary appropriately. I guess you have to write something similar like

```
POI poi1 = new POI();
poi1.poiList()
```

Instead of

```
POI poi1 =new POI();
poi1.List();
```

EDIT: You also have to provide a mechanism to get the data from your dictionary to your form, either by making the dictionary itself `public` (which is highly not recommended) or by using the following:

Within your `POI`-class add these two methods:

```
public bool ContainsKey(string key) { return this.poi.ContainsKey(key) ; }
public List<string> GetValue(string key) { return this.poi[key]; }
```

Those two methods can now be used within your form:

```
if (poi1.ContainsKey(txt))
{
    List<string> points = poi1.GetValue(txt);
    Combo_list2.Items.Clear();
    Combo_list2.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I have modified my code in the answer section. But bow it is showing error for poi1 in the seledctedindexchange method

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly What I wanted to do.